# How is engine thrust monitored during flight?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, engines, telemetry

The failure of the Falcon 9 first stage landing during the [Eutelsat/ABS mission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLNmtUEvI5A) was attributed to:

> [thrust was low on 1 of 3 landing engines](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/743097337782763521)

which indicate that engine thrusts are part of the telemetry data.
I can see how the thrust can be measured on a test stand.  But how can they be monitored during the flight?

Comment: You could install load cells on the thrust frame. Those will tell you the amount of force the engine applies to the rocket. IDK if this is done in practice though.

Answer (score 2):

In the SSME the "thrust control loop's" independent variable was chamber pressure.

> During the engine run phase, the MOV, MFV, and CCV are switched to run
>   schedules, while the OPOV and  FPOV  are  switched  to  closed-loop 
>   operations.    The  run  schedules  for  the  MOV  and  MFV  cause
>   them to simply remain fully open, whereas the run schedule for the CCV
>   drives it between half open at 67 percent thrust (MPL) and fully open
>   at 100 percent thrust (and above).  This action maintains the
>   appropriate  flow  relationships  among  the  several  parallel  fuel 
>   flow  paths  as  the  HPFTP  output pressure varies with thrust. 
>   During engine run, the OPOV and FPOV are used as control devices for
>   thrust and mixture ratio.  Manipulating these valves affects the
>   output of the preburners, the speed of the  turbopumps,  and, 
>   therefore,  the  propellant  flowrates.    **The  FPOV  is  driven 
>   alone  to  maintain mixture ratio in the MCC, while the OPOV is driven
>   with the FPOV to increase or decrease thrust while maintaining  the 
>   mixture  ratio.**    **The  control  loops  include  the  controller,  the
>   valve  actuators,  and  the transducers that sense flowrates and MCC
>   pressure; i.e., thrust.**

from [here](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf), emphasis mine

And this which is a bit more explicit

> If no malfunctions are discovered, the closed loop thrust control
>   system is activated at 2.4 seconds. The MEC compares the measured MCC
>   chamber pressure to a preprogramed chamber pressure ramp to RPL and
>   modulates the OPOV in an attempt to zero out any differences.

from [here](http://www.enginehistory.org/SSME/SSME3.pdf)

Acronymology:

MOV Main Oxidizer Valve

MFV Main Fuel Valve

CCV Chamber Coolant Valve aka Coolant Control Valve

OPOV Oxidizer Preburner Oxidizer Valve

FPOV Fuel Preburner Oxidizer Valve

MPL Minimum Power Level

HPFTP High Pressure Fuel TurboPump

MCC Main Combustion Chamber

MEC Main Engine Controller (SSMEC preferred because MEC also is Master Events Controller)

RPL Rated Power Level

Answer (score 0):

They get a fair bit of telemetry from the engines. Over time, SpaceX has indicated they have instrumented their engines to greater and greater degrees.

Recall that a rocket engines thrust is mostly determined by the fuel (and oxidizer) flow. These are pumped by turbopumps, which SpaceX has innovated on in their engines.

A turbopump spins and moves fuel. When the fuel flow is lower than expected the turbopump is running lighter and can detect that difference.

Secondarily in this case, it is likely that the low thrust engine was one of the two side engines, in which case they would have gotten feedback that the stage was flying off-kilter due to unbalanced thrust.